# How to mock method's local variables/variable methods using Mockito

Tags: mocking, mockito, junit4, powermockito, junit5

I have a class named `A` and method `method1()` in it:

```
Class A{

    boolean method1(String path){
        File procDir = new File(path);
        if(!procDir.exists()){
            return false`;
        }
        if(!procDir.canRead()){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Considering above code would anyone suggest, the way to mack the method1 and inner method/variables (`procDir.canRead()`) .

Comment: Please put details such as `current source code to be tested should not be modified`, something in that area. Answers here will be based on the circumstances you will mentioned besides the problem you stated. There are answers for problems here but not all solutions apply to all.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer is: you can't with Mockito alone.

You need a mocking framework capable of mocking calls to `new`. Such as PowerMock(ito) or JMockit. You can find documentation for how to do that using PowerMock [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor). In that sense, technically this is a *solved* problem - it only requires some twiddling to get it to work (if you get one of the pre-reqs wrong, it simply will not work).

But beyond that, the other answers are spot on: you created **hard to test** code, and now you are looking for a band-aid to work around the consequences of your inflexible design.

So instead of spending valuable time on twiddling with PowerMock(ito) - follow the advise you already got and fix the **root cause** of your test problem. For example by using some sort of dependency injection to provide a File object to this code (instead of having this code call `new` itself).

Comment: I totally agree with your assessment here. Well said.

Comment: i agree, However, given that we don't know the circumstances under which this question is asked, we cannot conclude that above assessment must be followed (i.e a hard to test code should have, in the first place, been designed properly.). In that regards, i might assume that the question pertains to a legacy code where OP does not have control of (even refactoring the code would cost much or under no circumstances the legacy code should be modified).

Comment: @lemoncodes Sure, but the OP never came back to give more details, so whatever anyway ;-(

Comment: Your comment is 100% gold. I am back to Java after 4 years of Node/Jest, it took me a day to figure out why my tests are not mocking method scoped objects. I am rewriting my components now to decouple them, its not about making them testable but rather writing the test driven code. (Although I am not fan of TDD, its expensive, once you understand the concept, you can achieve better quality without wasting TDD). Probably going on bit tangent but those who get this comment might get that its a matter of principle :) cheers.

Comment: Fun fact: in the meantime, Mockito made quite some progress, you can now mock calls to `new`, too, see https://davidvlijmincx.com/posts/mockito_mock_constructor/. But I still do not recommend it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of design as the method is tightly coupled to `File`

> The [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) states:
>
> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.

With that in mind, consider refactoring the method to explicitly depend on the `File`

```
boolean method1(File procDir){    
    if(!procDir.exists()){
      return false`;
    }

    if(!procDir.canRead()){
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Which also inverts the creation of the dependency to a delegate external to the class/method. This also lets the method state explicitly what it *actually needed*.

Now that the method is decoupled the method can be tested by passing a proper File or mock.

You can also consider abstracting `File`

```
public interface FileInfo {
    boolean exists();
    boolean canRead()
}
```

as classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions.

```
boolean method1(FileInfo procDir){    
    if(!procDir.exists()){
      return false`;
    }

    if(!procDir.canRead()){
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The implementation of `FileInfo` can then encapsulate an actual `File` and expose the desired behavior.

For testing is should easier now to mock/stub/fake the abstraction either directly by inheritance or a mocking framework.

```
FileInfo file = mock(FileInfo.class);

when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);

subject.method1(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JUnit's [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule (or, if using JUnit5, its [equivalent extension](https://github.com/glytching/junit-extensions)) to create an input file for your test(s).

You would then ...

- Pass the path to this file into `method1()` - to test the happy path
- Pass a non existent file path into `method1()` to test the `!procDir.exists()` sad path

On completion of the test JUnit will discard the temporary folder, thereby adhering to the test principle of self containment.

This approach allows you to test your code without any mocking whilst still being a self contained unit test.

Alternatively you could hide the `File procDir = new File(path);` call behind an interface:

```
public interface FileCreator {
    File create(String path);
}
```

With a simple implementation:

```
public class FileCreatorImpl implements FileCreator {
    public File create(String path) {
        return new File(path);    
    }
}
```

When testing, you could inject a `Mock(FileCreator.class)` into the instance of the class which contains `method1()` and set expectations on that instance as follows:

```
String filePath = "...";
File file = Mockito.mock(File.class);
Mockito.when(fileCreator.create(filePath)).thenReturn(file);

// happy path
Mockito.when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(file.canRead()).thenReturn(true);
assertThat(sut.method1(filePath), is(true));

// sad path 1
Mockito.when(file.exists()).thenReturn(false);
assertThat(sut.method1(filePath), is(false));

// sad path 2
Mockito.when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(file.canRead()).thenReturn(false);
assertThat(sut.method1(filePath), is(false));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sure this implementation will work for me.